# JTable - same items displayed

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt

As you can see when am trying a new items got like this repetition. What should I do?

[image]

I wrote a `JTable` redisplayer class. So have an add button to table. When click that button it should be for exp I addded 1. After I add 2. Should be display 1 2 only. Not 1 1 2 like that.

```
     jTable1.removeAll();
     jTable1.revalidate();
     try{
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     }
     catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
          System.err.println("Driver yok");
            return;
     }
     Connection con=null;
         try{
         con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kutuphane","root","");
         System.out.println("Veritabnı baglandıldı");
         Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM kisiler ");

     while(rs.next()){
         model=(DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
         model.insertRow(i,new Object[]{rs.getString("ADSOYAD"),rs.getInt("TELEFON"),rs.getInt("TCNO"),rs.getString("ADRES")   } );
         i++;   
     }
      jTable1.setModel(model);
      jTable1.revalidate();

      stmt.close();
      rs.close();
    }
     catch(SQLException e){
     System.out.println("Veritabanı baglanmadi");
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
     finally{
        if(con!=null)
        try{
            con.close();
    }
     catch(SQLException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You should edit your post and remove the link to the image and include it in your question. Also don't use so mani upper case words as it make it difficult to read.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UGWZE.png its my problem thanks

Comment: Guys plz let me know what u dont understand ? I'll try to explain exactly

Comment: do not intialize `model` in while loop, it will create new model till `rs.next()` is valid..

Comment: First you should stop SHOUTING as us..

Comment: `jTable1.removeAll();
     jTable1.revalidate();` Don't do this at all, just `jTable1.setModel(model);` & then also remove the `jTable1.revalidate();`  immediately after it...

Comment: am so sorry dunno upper case means in english shouting sorry about that .Thank you but seems same problem again

Comment: I deleted jTable1.removeAll(); jTable1.revalidate(); these & jTable1.revalidate(); after set model .

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

First, get rid of this line at the top of your code

```
jTable1.removeAll();    //DELETE THIS LINE!!
```

You are probably expecting it to remove all the lines from you table model, but that's not what does.

Next, replace the `while` loop and the two lines after it with:

```
model = new DefaultTableModel();
while(rs.next()){
     model.addRow(new Object[]{
        rs.getString("ADSOYAD"),
        rs.getInt("TELEFON"),
        rs.getInt("TCNO"),
        rs.getString("ADRES")}
     );   
 }
 jTable1.setModel(model);
```

NOTE that I am using `addRow` instead of `insertRow`, so `i` is probably no longer necessary.

Comment: Thank you but after model = new DefaultTableModel(); this jtable disappear .Changes  does not appear.

Comment: I think you need to clear out the old rows before starting to add the new ones.  That's what I was trying to accomplish by creating the model anew.  But you could also try this: while(model.getRowCount()>0) model.removeRow(0);  Also be sure to set i to zero before starting to insert new rows.

Comment: Just use `model.setRowCount(0)` to remove rows of data from a `DefaultTableModel`.